# How do you include a local jar when using mvn assembly:single to build a jar-with-dependencies?

Tags: java, maven, jvm, jython, maven-assembly-plugin

Specifically, I am trying to build a Datomic (http://www.datomic.com) jar with dependencies so that I can experiment with it in the Jython REPL.

Datomic is not distributed on Maven, but you can download and install Datomic into your local Maven repo like this:

```
mvn install:install-file 
  -DgroupId=com.datomic 
  -DartifactId=datomic 
  -Dfile=datomic.jar 
  -DpomFile=pom.xml
```

But I need it as single jar with its dependencies so I can put it in my classpath and use it from the Jython REPL.

`mvn assembly:single` builds a jar with dependencies, but it doesn't include the Datomic jar, presumably because it's a local file.

How do you include a local jar when doing `mvn assembly:single`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you will be better off with the Maven Shade Plugin:
http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/

This will allow you to create a single *über-jar*, which will contain both your own classes as well as dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter if the jar is installed locally, as long as you add the jar file to your project's pom.xml file (dependencies section):

```
<dependencies>
  ... ...
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.datomic</groupId>
    <artifactId>datomic</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Check out Maven Assembly Plugin docum [jar-with-dependency](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/descriptor-refs.html#jar-with-dependencies):

> Use jar-with-dependencies as the descriptorRef of your assembly-plugin configuration in order to create a JAR which contains the binary output of your project, along its the unpacked dependencies. This built-in descriptor produces an assembly with the classifier jar-with-dependencies using the JAR archive format.
>
> Note that jar-with-dependencies provides only basic support for uber-jars. For more control, use the [Maven Shade Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/).

Sample pom.xml:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.3</version>
  <configuration>
    <descriptorRefs><descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef></descriptorRefs>
  </configuration>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <phase>package</phase>
      <goals><goal>single</goal></goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```